# Passing an additional parameter with an onChange event with custom component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

On my component I use a custom component for displaying numbers- I need `onChange` to get the input value, I have tried the below but I get a type error:

> Type '(event: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() =>
>   void'.ts(2322)

```
export default function Test({param}) {

  const onChange = key => event => {
    const value = parseInt(event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))
    const x = {...param.x}
    x.y[key] = value

    setX(param => ({
      ...param,
      payment: x
    }))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <NumberListItem
        label="test"
        value={(param.payment)}
        onChange={onChange('payment')}
        inputProps={{decimalScale: 0, suffix: ' %'}}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

`NumberListItem` component:

```
export default function NumberListItem({
  value = '',
  onChange = () => {},
  ...rest
}) {
  return (
    <ListItem>
      <NumberField
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        {...rest}
      />
    </ListItem>
  )
}
```

`NumberField` component:

```
export default function NumberField(props: TextFieldProps & NumberFormatProps) {
  return (
    <TextField
      {...props}
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: change `onChange = () => {}` to `onChange = (e: any) => {}`

Comment: @BeHappy But then I'm getting a `'e' is defined but never used` error

Comment: Where did you do that? What I said, is just set prop type.

Comment: @BeHappy I changed the `onChange = () => {}` on `NumberListItem` to `onChange = (e: any) => {}`

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set prop type:

```
export interface NumberListItemProps {
  value: string;
  onChange: (e:any) => {};
  [props: string]: any;
}
export default function NumberListItem({
  value = '',
  onChange,
  ...rest
}: NumberListItemProps) {
  return (
    <ListItem>
      <NumberField
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        {...rest}
      />
    </ListItem>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a type error: `Type '(event: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(e: any) => {}'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{}'` If I change `onChange: (e: any) => {}` to `  onChange: (e: any) => void` the `onChange` param won't be optional anymore, how can I keep it optional?

Comment: Would you share your `NumberField` component?

Comment: You have to `onChange?: (e:any) => {}` to make `onChange` optional.